# How to connect configure Entity Framework to connect to SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm setting up the SQL Server connection for Entity Framework Core having two more systems and connection via LAN, SQL installed in only one system? So, let me know how to connect DB for another system. Below see my code...

**First code:**

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<CatalogDbContext>(Option=Option.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=MACHINE-2;Initial Catalog=ShoppingCart;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"));
```

**Second Code:**

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<CatalogDbContext>
(Option=>Option.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=192.168.2.2;Initial Catalog=ShoppingCart;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"));
```

first code connection successfully and second code not to connect DB?

Comment: public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<CatalogDbContext> 
  (Option=>Option.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=MACHINE-2;Initial 
  Catalog=ShoppingCart;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"));      
}

Comment: public void Configure Services(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<CatalogDbContext> 
   (Option=>Option.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=192.168.2.2;Initial 
    Catalog=ShoppingCart;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"));      
}
This is not connecting DB

Comment: Do not post long code blocks in the comments. If it should be part of the question, then edit it into the question, and take the time to properly format it.

Comment: Also, you're not trying to connect Visual Studio Code to SQL DB. Just because you're using Visual Studio Code to develop your application doesn't mean that's what you're trying to connect. You'd have the same issue with Notepad, Sublime, or VI or any other editor or IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect two server for one DbContext. CatalogDbContext will connect only one server. Create another dbContext and try this `services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer().AddDbContext<AnotherDbContext>` .

Now you can use `MACHINE-2` server for `CatalogDbContext` and `192.168.2.2` server for `AnotherDbContext`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try creating another DbContext to connect to the other Data Source. The same way you connected to he first one will work but with a different DB Context.